# Firebase - remove something by value

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I'm creating advanced chatbot and I'm using Firebase to store names, chat bans, messages.
I want to remove something by value, so, if I banned user "test", i want to remove that same user with "test".

Here is my Firebase ban structure:
[image: Firebase ban structure]
So, i want to remove "-KCXvmm_M-Nd7sR724hJ" by value (name), is that even possible?

ref: `var banRef = new Firebase('application.firebaseio.com/ban');`
Push: `banRef.push({name:'test1'});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be a simple matter of:

```
ref.orderByValue().equalTo('test1').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.ref().remove();
});
```

Note that the query may match multiple children, in which case the `child_added` event will fire for each child and they'll all get removed.